# how to stop looping and wait until different value received from serial

Tags: c, loops, serial-port, avr

hi i planning to made a multiple servo controlling with serial as control trigger signal on AVR with C and codevision

but when the trigger is true, the servo running in crazy loop, it back to original position (0 degree) instead of stay on desired position, my tutor give me hint to use "wait ... until" statement with the old data comparison but i'm not found the way to utilize it yet on google

because utilizing break; at the end of the if left the chip freeze until it reset

and the old code(it runs the servo forth and back continously)

```
 while (1)
      {           
      while(UCSRA & (1<<RXC))  
          {
      // Place your code here
           //data=UDR;

           PORTC=UDR;
           data=UDR;
           //PORTB=data;
           } ;

          if (data== 0x0A || data== 0x0B)
          {     
                if (data== 0x0A)
                  {     
                        old_data=data;

                        PORTA=0x00;
                        PORTA.1=1;
                        movservo0(90,7);
                        movservo1(15,3);



                   }    

                if (data== 0x0B)
                  {     
                        old_data=data;

                        PORTA=0x00;
                        PORTA.1=1;
                        movservo0(15,3);
                        movservo1(90,7);


                   } 


           }
}
```

as for movservo0 (another movservo() almost had same code)

```
void set_servo1(unchar derajat)
{   unchar n;

    servo2=1;
    delay_us(750);
    for(n=0; n<derajat; n++)
    {
        delay_us(12);

    };
    servo2=0;
    delay_ms(10);
}

void movservo0(unsigned char sudut, unsigned char speed)
{
     unchar i;
    set_servo1(sudut);
    for (i=1;i<=sudut;i+=speed){
    set_servo1(i);
    delay_ms(100/speed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This new code is a bit better.

The top of the `while(UCSRA & (1<<RXC))` loop is fine this way. The loop body will only be entered if there is a character to be read. (Although, I'm not sure why you are expecting to read '\n' or vertical tab.)

A minor problem is the way the UDR is read. The act of reading UDR erases the contents. So you should be using

```
data=UDR;    
PORTC=data;
```

The jumping of the servos appears to be in the `moveservo()` function. This function always sets the angle to 1 and then gradually increases the angle of the servo until it reaches the desired angle.

`setservo()` appears to be an attempt to perform PWM to drive a servo, but it doesn't work correctly. To keep the servo at a desired angle, you have to keep switching the pin from 0 to 1 at the correct times, not just once like this function does. Have you looked at the PWM functions of the timers? You just set these up and they run in the background. An alternative is to use a timer to set an interrupt to wake up and toggle the pins as you need.

If you want to do the switching of the pins without interrupts, then you should be using delays in the `while(1)` loop itself. Just use the `setservo()` functions to change some variables.

```
while(1)
{
    // read the UART if ready and set the target values
    // this part only runs occasionally
    while(UCSRA & (1<<RXC))  
    {
        // etc
    }

    // The rest of the loop body runs every time

    // adjust the servo values toward the target values
    // use a counter to determine if to adjust during this loop iteration
    // e.g., a slow speed counts to a higher number before adjusting

    delay(750);

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_INTERVALS; ++i)
    {
        // decide whether to set pins to 1 or 0 based on the servo values
        delay(INTERVAL);
    }
}
```

I don't know about your particular servos, but they typically have a period where most of the time the pin is 0, and then a short time in the period where the pin is 1. You will need to adjust NUM_INTERVALS and INTERVAL and 750 to add up to the correct length of time.

---

There is so much wrong with this snippet, it is hard to start. It is difficult to say why the servo is moving, as it is only ever "moved" to the same value every time. (Unless, you have omitted some code that sets it to some other value.)

Typically, when receiving UART, the processor should wait until the character is received. This is accomplished by this

```
while(UCSRA & (1<<RXC) == 0);
```

Note the `;` creating an empty body of the while loop. This is probably what your tutor meant. When the flag is set, then the loop exits and the data is ready to be read.

```
while(UCSRA & (1<<RXC) == 0);
data = UDR;
```

Next, you have a block which looks like you meant to be part of a `while` loop, but it isn't. The body of the loop is the single statement abbove it. The block gets executed every time.

```
  {
     if(data=0x0a)
     {
        olddata=data;
        movservo0(90,7); //move servo to certain degree
      }
  }
```

Another error is the condition in the `if` statement. It looks like you are trying to test if `data` is 0x0A, but that is not what is happening. Instead, you set `data` to be 0x0A, and then execute the inner part every time. The condition you probably want is `if(data == 0x0A)`. Note the `==` instead of `=`.

So your code is equivalent to

```
while(1)
{
  while(ucsra & (1<<RXC)) data=udr; // maybe read UDR into data

  data=0x0a; // set data anyway

  olddata=data;
  movservo0(90,7); //move servo to certain degree
}
```

Again, for the jumping servo, I suspect some code that is omitted here that is also runs every time. Or else, the `moveservo()` function has a problem itself.

Comment: ah sorry i didn't paste the code directly from the IDE back then

Comment: ah yes this part is solved! even though another problem just occured, and very appreciate your effort for assisting me in this